# Question deleted - notified about comment - can't read it.

Tags: support, deleted-questions

A closed question which I asked a while ago has been deleted.  I got a comment notification that says "Deleting this question since it's..." but when I click to read the full comment, I obviously can't, since I can't view deleted questions (shouldn't I be able to see my own, though?)

Link:
https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3951/should-a-ui-designer-use-a-mac

So, to the moderator that deleted it, can you please post the comment you left here?

Regardless, if the deletion is because of the comments (as I suspect it was, since it gathered a new comment yesterday) — can't we just delete the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was already closed. I deleted it because it was attracting a lot of discussion that in my opinion doesn't meet Stack Exchange's objective of *making the internet better.*

I've undeleted the question so we can talk about whether it has any value -- with or without the comments.

Comment: My personal opinion is that questions can be judged by the answers, but questions/answers should never be judged on comments.  As [I suggested on Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/how-do-our-moderators-and-community-members-feel-about-cleaning-up-comment-nois), comments just need to be cleaned up. Blow away the whole comment stack.  It's noise.  It's a conversation between (mostly) two people that is finished.  Nothing about it is worth persisting.

Comment: @Renesis Sorry, but even if we blow away the comments, I don't see any reason to keep this question around. I just remembered that [we talked about it already](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/219/closing-of-subjective-questions).

Comment: Patrick, the problem is not whether the question is "good", it's that you are misusing deletion.  By your argument shouldn't all closed questions be deleted?  For one thing, there was at least one good answer to the question.

Comment: @Renesis No, I didn't delete it because it was closed. I deleted it because it was flame-bait (despite your best intentions and efforts to discourage flames).

Comment: And yes, Hisham's answer was very good. I just don't think that was enough to counter the drawbacks.

Comment: I can accept that.  I disagree slightly.  I think that the *topic should be able to not be flame-bait* (in other words, edited for improvement), even if I didn't accomplish that goal.  But, if it's likely to keep drawing it (even closed), then I don't object.  I still feel annoyed that I can't personally view it, I guess I'll post about that on Meta.SO.

Comment: @Renesis Okay, I've undeleted it again so *you* can delete it -- then you should still be able to see it. I agree you should always be able to see your own content. If you post on MSO, share a link here. :)

Comment: That runs us into another dead-end -- as a normal user, I can't delete my own posts if they contain answers.  Only moderators (or 10k on downvoted questions) can delete questions with answers.

Comment: @Renesis Oh well. I'll email you a copy if you want.

Comment: It appears it's [already been asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) on Meta, and declined.  Though it seems like it probably needs to be revisited.

Comment: @Renesis: just a FYI - closing is essentially the precursor to deletion: if you see a closed question you think has value for the site, argue for it to be re-opened, merged, etc... Otherwise, chances are it'll disappear sooner or later.